# QNetworkReply https API doesn't work on Android devices - QT

Tags: android, c++, qt, api, qnetworkrequest

I've a problem, I'm make an app with qt, cross platoform, ios & android.
So when i call this code:

```
QList<QString> JsonFunctions::getToken(QString Username, QString Password)
{
    QString lista;
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));

    QJsonObject json;

    json.insert("username", Username);
    json.insert("password", Password);
    json.insert("client_id","10");
    json.insert("client_secret","xxx");
    json.insert("scope","xxx");
    json.insert("grant_type","password");
    json.insert("accept", "application/json");

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://xxxxx/api/v2/login"));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

    QSslConfiguration conf = request.sslConfiguration();
    conf.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
    request.setSslConfiguration(conf);

    QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.post(request, QJsonDocument(json).toJson());
    eventLoop.exec();

    QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << "reply" << strReply;
    qDebug() << "code" << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject responseObject = doc.object();

    QString token_type = responseObject.value("token_type").toString();
    QString access_token = responseObject.value("access_token").toString();
    QString refresh_token = responseObject.value("refresh_token").toString();

    QList<QString> lists;
    lists.append(token_type);
    lists.append(access_token);
    lists.append(refresh_token);

    return lists;
}
```

The problem is that on android this code don't work.
Instead on ios everything works. the reply on android is empty.

Maybe because the https url create a problem on android call ? I don't understand how to fix it.
I've set on the device many permission in the manifest, internet permission is setted.

Now, many idea to works ? I'm testing on asus zen pad 3s and iphone 7. Only on android don't work. Why ? I use qt 5.9

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) should be used as asynchronous API. 
   When the request is finished [finished(QNetworkReply *reply)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) signal is emitted. Connect to this signal and read data in it.
2. If you really need to make it "synchronous" connect finished signal to [exit()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html#exit) slot of eventLoop. Also better check if there was any [SSL errors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#sslErrors) before.
3. You will need OpenSSL libs for some Android devices. This was causing troubles for me. OpenSSL/libcrypto.so and OpenSSL/libssl.so was needed. Even if [QSslSocket::supportsSsl()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#supportsSsl) returns true.

Comment: Qt https requests work fine on iOS and older Android such as Android 4.4 Kit Kat.  One newer Android versions, QSslSocket::supportsSsl() may return true, however there is no libcrypto.so available for your Qt app to link with.  In the debugger I can see "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_ctrl".  Building OpenSSL on a mac using clang is a challenge.  See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html